# Install Ubuntu touch on x86 tablet

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-touch, tablet

Is there any way to install Ubuntu touch on an x86 tablet? Some images are available for download over there http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-touch/daily-preinstalled/pending but I don't know if I can somehow download and install them on my tablet.

Comment: if you can install ubuntu on it regularly, or other linux systems - I would download the ubuntu desktop next iso and try that

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid (or hope so?) that all the answers I found so far, searching for the same question, are simply off topic.

Because x86 tablets are NOT ARM devices, those should be regular PCs with some Intel CPU.
The only points to answer, should be how to get GRUB in, and whether certain hardware has its drivers.
The rest should be the same on tiny 7" x86 tablets, as on any standard desktop - with touch screen, which is just a kind of mouse.

So the partial answer is, NOT ubuntu-touch - do not search for images for ARM CPUs, when yours is Intel x86 (and 64-bit).
What is missing is "howto" make that device boot GRUB (perhaps 32-bit EFI?) on certain tablets, and install Ubuntu - "normal" PC Desktop version.

Well, and onscreen keyboard for touch devices, is part of  Ubuntu Desktop, its name is "Onboard". And light desktop environments (xfce4, Xubuntu) may be preferred on tiny devices, to avoid slowdown..

Comment: I don't think this is correct. I'm playing with Ubuntu on a Dell Venue 11 (I5 x86 tablet) and while I'm making headway with "onboard etc" it doesn't seem possible to do Full Disk Encryption without plugging in a keyboard (but I think home directory encryption might work), nor does device rotation work seemlessly, and the GUI needs LOTS of tweeks to make it - sort if - useable.

Answer (score 0):

I was recently wondering the same thing, so I researched it and found an article that has very easy and simple steps, and lists what you need. It can be found here:

http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/linux/3531970/how-install-ubuntu-touch/

Good luck.

*WARNING! UBUNTU TOUCH IS NOT FULLY DEVELOPED YET, AND MAY HARM YOUR DEVICE IF NOT INSTALLED PROPERLY! IT IS RECOMMENDED THAT YOU INSTALL IT ON AN EXTRA OR UNIMPORTANT PHONE/TABLET!

Comment: Those are Android instructions

Comment: @AleksandrDubinsky Although that's probably not the correct answer because I think the Ubuntu touch images are for arm devices, there are some intel based Android devices out there.

Answer (score -3):

Step 1:

With Ubuntu installed on your PC, ensure you have the universe archive enabled. This is a software repository which is probably commented out – you need to remove the # which precedes it in the file /etc/apt/sources.list

You can find detailed information on how to add repositories here

With Ubuntu universe archive enabled, now you can install the ubuntu-device-flash package – the main tool for installing Ubuntu Touch - as follows.

Step 2:  (you can skip this if you’re already running 14.04 as the tools are already included).

You’ll need tools in the Phablet Tools PPA in order to install Ubuntu for devices. These are included in 12.04 Precise onwards. On your PC, press Ctrl+Alt+T to start a terminal.

Add the Phablet Tools PPA by typing (at the $ prompt): sudo add-apt-repository ppa:phablet-team/tools

On Ubuntu 12.04, add the Ubuntu SDK Release PPA by typing: sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa

Update your system to use the latest packages by typing: sudo apt-get update

Install the ubuntu-device-flash package by typing: sudo apt-get install ubuntu-device-flash

For help with the ubuntu-device-flash tool type: man ubuntu-device-flashYou can type q to exit.

Step 3:

Install phablet-tools package by typing: sudo apt-get install phablet-tools

List its tools by typing: dpkg -L phablet-tools | grep bin

Note that you can show a tool’s help by adding –h. For example: phablet-config -h

Step 4:You need to enable Android Developer Mode on your device. To do this, head to Settings and tap About phone (or About tablet) then about. Now tap Build number seven times and you will see a pop-up saying you are now a developer.

You will now have a new menu in Settings called Developer options. Go in here and tick the box next to USB Debugging.  Enabling USB Debugging allows you to send commands to your USB connected device from the terminal.Step 5:

Connect your device via a USB cable to your PC running Ubuntu. You’ll be prompted in Android to authorise it. To check the connection is working, type (at the prompt) adb devices

You should see your device listed with a series of numbers and letters. If your device isn’t shown, try first typing: adb kill-server

Step 6:

If you haven’t already done so, now is the time to back up your Android apps and data. Also, note down your device type and build ID because you will probably want to reinstall Android later (you’ll have to download the factory image and use the adb and fastboot tools to install it).Step 7:

To install Ubuntu, you need to unlock your device’s bootloader. This process wipes the phone or tablet.

To do this, type at the prompt (as a reminder, hit Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal): adb reboot bootloader Now unlock the bootloader by typing: sudo fastboot oem unlock

You’ll see a warning on screen. To change from no to yes, use the volume rocker, and to select the option, press the power button.

Now reboot the device by typing: fastboot reboot

You will be taken through the initial setup. Don’t worry about entering much information as you’re about to remove Android completely by installing Ubuntu.

Step 8:

Power off your device using the power button.

Reboot into the bootloader by using the correct physical button combination for your device For example, the combination for the Nexus 5 is to hold down the volume up, volume down and power buttons simultaneously.

Install Ubuntu by typing: ubuntu-device-flash --channel=devel --bootstrap

The installation should happen automatically with no input from you. It will take a while – the image is initially downloaded to the ~/.cache/ubuntuimages folder on your PC before being transferred to your smartphone or tablet.

To begin with, Ubuntu is a ‘recovery’ image which you device will boot from. Then, Ubuntu is installed as an OS in its own right. On the next reboot, you should see Ubuntu running.

Step 9:

After installing Ubuntu, you can head to Settings > Updates to get the latest version, and choose whether or not updates are installed automatically.

Comment: Hi MineLover729, you will have to include an attribution (to: By Jim Martin | 15 May 2015) and a source (https://www.techadvisor.co.uk/how-to/linux/how-install-ubuntu-touch-image-3531970/) , but simple complete copies are undesirable.